# Adding DOM-event to multiple elements and affecting on children's style

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am new to javascript and struggling with one issue I cannot find solution for.
I have few divs with class ''details'' with their childrens ''expander-bottom''. I want to simulate situation that whenever I click on ''details'' div its children changes height from 0 to 550px. I know how to do it for single element using div's id but I don't want to duplicate the code setting specific id for each element and assigning function to it. I would like to make it in few lines using class name;

Here is code for two divs:

```
<div class="details">
        Details  
        <div class="expander-bottom" style="height: 0px;" onclick="clickDiv()">                              
              <div class="text-prices">
                  <h1>Prices:</h1> <br>
                  Small: 5$<br>
                  Medium: 7$<br>
                  Large: 10$
              </div>         
        </div>           
</div> 

<div class="details">
            Details  
            <div class="expander-bottom" style="height: 0px;" onclick="clickDiv()">                              
                  <div class="text-prices">
                      <h1>Prices:</h1> <br>
                      Small: 6$<br>
                      Medium: 8$<br>
                      Large: 11$
                  </div>         
            </div>           
</div>
```

And my javascript code for single element using id instead of class so as you can see I also had to use children's id:

```
function clickDiv(){  
var a = document.getElementById("expander-bottom"); 
    if(a.style.height=="0px"){
        a.style.height = "550px";
    }
    else if(a.style.height>="0px"){
        a.style.height = "0px";
    }   
}
```

And so it works for one element and to make it work for other elements I'll need to assign specific id for parent and children and duplicate function as many times as amount of elements.

I tried to use eventListeners making code like below:

```
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName("details");
var childrens = document.getElementsByClassName("expander-bottom");
for(var i=0;i<parents.length;i++){
    parents[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(childrens[i].style.height=="0px"){
            childrens[i].style.height = "550px";
        }
        else if(childrens[i].style.height>="0px"){
        childrens[i].style.height = "0px";
        }
    }, false);
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to use DOM event listener in thins case to make it work or any other better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try the below example.

```js
const detailsElements = document.querySelectorAll(".details");
for (let i = 0; i < detailsElements.length; i++) {
  detailsElements[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    let child = this.querySelector('.expander-bottom');
    if (child.style.height == "0px") {
      child.style.height = "550px";
    }
    else if (child.style.height >= "0px") {
      child.style.height = "0px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.details{
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="details">
        Details  
        <div class="expander-bottom" style="height: 0px;" >                              
              <div class="text-prices">
                  <h1>Prices:</h1> <br>
                  Small: 5$<br>
                  Medium: 7$<br>
                  Large: 10$
              </div>         
        </div>           
</div> 

<div class="details">
            Details  
            <div class="expander-bottom" style="height: 550px;">                              
                  <div class="text-prices">
                      <h1>Prices:</h1> <br>
                      Small: 6$<br>
                      Medium: 8$<br>
                      Large: 11$
                  </div>         
            </div>           
</div>
```

Comment: If the answer solves your problem can you please vote it

Comment: That solved my problem. let child = this.querySelector('.expander-bottom');  <<< this line placed in proper place does the job. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName("details");
var childrens = document.getElementsByClassName("expander-bottom");
for(var i=0;i<parents.length;i++){
    (function(i){
        parents[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            if(childrens[i].style.height=="0px"){
                childrens[i].style.height = "550px";
            }
            else if(childrens[i].style.height>="0px"){
            childrens[i].style.height = "0px";
            }
        }, false);
    })(i)
}
```

also don't forget to close your div class here `<div class="details>`

Comment: Yes, I've already noticed lack of quotation mark there :) But your solution doesn't work as well.

Comment: the problem is that var statements are not block scoped, closure function helps here but that could be solved easily with ES6 let statement, but as you're beginner I thought you haven't herd about it

Comment: I haven't heard about it yet. I just jumped one week ago from C# to JS so I'm totally new. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. As if I didn't have access to style attribute getting elements by class name I think.